# The Proper way of Returning Exception in Oracle REST API with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, rest, api, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I Use Oracle REST API for my rest service with Oracle Sql Developer. My question is How to return a messge like "Parameter is null" using only Oracle rest api and oracle sql developer? If i raise excepetion in my procedure ORACLE REST API return HTTP 500 - internal server error, i'd like to return only a message that "parameter is null" instead of "Http 500 - internal server erro", but i use only Oracle REST API and oracle sql developer.

The code of procedure that i'm testing is below (i get from oracle documetation, just include the exception):

```
create or replace procedure promote(l_empno        in number,
                                    l_job          IN varchar2,
                                    l_mgr          IN number,
                                    l_sal          IN number,
                                    l_comm         IN number,
                                    l_deptno       IN number,
                                    l_salarychange OUT number
                                    ) is
  oldsalary number;
begin

   IF l_job IS NULL THEN
     raise_application_error(-20101, 'Parameter is null');
   end if;

  select nvl(e.sal, 0) into oldsalary FROM emp e where e.empno = l_empno;

  update emp e
     set e.job    = nvl(l_job, e.job),
         e.mgr    = nvl(l_mgr, e.mgr),
         e.sal    = nvl(l_sal, e.sal),
         e.comm   = nvl(l_comm, e.comm),
         e.deptno = nvl(l_deptno, e.deptno)
   where e.empno = l_empno;
  l_salarychange := nvl(l_sal, oldsalary) - oldsalary;

end;
```

Comment: that should be coming back on the response header, but it's NOT - BUG, will try to fix for next release of Oracle REST Data Services

Comment: How is this being called? via auto-rest or a plsql source rest service ?

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I'm guessing that you're using **Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS)**. Basic ORDS has limited ways for the developer to control the low-level HTTP response, but I think [this setting will probably do what you want](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e87809/troubleshooting-REST.htm#AELIG7229).

Edit your `defaults.xml` file and change this setting:

```
<entry key="debug.printDebugToScreen">true</entry>
```

This should make sure that the application error message (and stack trace) get returned as part of the JSON HTTP response.